# matlab loops for converting unit

Tags: matlab

```
while strcmp(unit, "oz") == 0 && strcmp(unit, "lb") == 0 && strcmp(unit, "ton") == 0 && strcmp(unit, "in") == 0 && strcmp(unit, "ft") == 0 && strcmp(unit, "mi") == 0 && strcmp(unit, "F") == 0 && strcmp(unit, "g") == 0 && strcmp(unit, "kg") == 0 && strcmp(unit, "tonne") == 0 && strcmp(unit, "cm") == 0 && strcmp(unit, "m") == 0 && strcmp(unit, "km") == 0 && strcmp(unit, "C") == 0
    if strcmp(unit_type, "mass") == 1
        while contains(unit, "oz") == 0 && strcmp(unit, "lb") == 0 && contains(unit, "ton") == 0 && contains(unit, "g") == 0 && strcmp(unit, "kg") == 0 && contains(unit, "tonne") == 0
            unit = input("Enter the unit: ","s");
        end

    elseif strcmp(unit_type, "temperature") == 1
        while contains(unit, "F") == 0 && contains(unit, "C") == 0
            unit = input("Enter the unit: ","s");
        end

    elseif strcmp(unit_type, "length") == 1
        while contains(unit, "in") == 0 && contains(unit, "ft") == 0 && contains(unit, "mi") == 0 && contains(unit, "cm") == 0 && contains(unit, "m") == 0 && contains(unit, "km") == 0
            unit = input("Enter the unit: ","s");
        end
    end
    
    disp('Error: Invalid input. Please enter a valid unit.');
    unit = input("Enter the unit: ","s");
end
```

up there is the piece of the scrip that i wrote for my converting unit program but the thing is I wanted to loop it for when the user wrongly input. For instance, when the user choose mass and input the unit of the value is km it should pop the error and request to input again. Could you guys help me with this? it still runs the rest of the code since the While condition is what im still working on it

What did you try and what were you expecting? for this section im still thinkign of another solution

Comment: Instead of `strcmp(unit, "oz") == 0` do `~strcmp(unit, "oz")`, it's shorter and easier to read. Even better, since you're using `"` strings, you can compare directly `unit ~= "oz"` (Note this does not work in Octave!). Next, create an array with your units, possibly by class, `mass_units = ["oz", "lb", "ton", ...]`, then you can do a lookup: `any(unit == mass_units)`.

Comment: what do you need hep with?